# Guava null pointer on multimap with multiple null values

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I'm using guava multimap (TreeMultiMap). I'm doing some unit tests to ensure it's ok but when I do the following test I get a null pointer exception from guava (I've cobbled together some code to recreate it). In the below just assume Location/Interconnect are simple classes. The natural order is by the id for the Location, i.e. 50, 51 in the code below.

```
Multimap<Location, Interconnect> interconnects;
interconnects = TreeMultimap.create();

Location l1 = new Location(50, "Test Location 1");
assertTrue(interconnects.put(l1, null));

Location l2 = new Location(51, "Test Location 2");
assertTrue(interconnects.put(l2, null));

//expect false but get null exception
assertFalse(locs.addLocation(l9));
```

I would have thought the last line being added would have returned simply false but it causes an exception.

If I change the null with a value they the second l9 returns false as I expected.

What's going wrong? All I could think of was Maps allow only one null key but this isn't a standard map and it isn't a key, it's the value.

The reason for testing this is I wish to allow adding of a Location without any values (as they may not be known) but then allow them to be added when they are known. I appreciate I can put in checks for duplicates with nulls but I want to know why it's failing in this scenario.

Comment: What is `locs`? And where is `addLocation` method?

Answer (score 4):

You're using a `TreeMultimap`, which means the values have to support the `compareTo` method.  Trying to use `compareTo` on `null` values will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Except that when you add one value, there's no other value to compare it to, so `compareTo` isn't called until the *second* value, at which point everything falls over.  `TreeSet` has similar issues, though they may have been fixed in more recent versions of Java.

Workarounds include using `Ordering.natural().nullsFirst()` or another null-accepting `Comparator` in the `TreeMultimap`, or using another `Multimap` implementation.

FWIW, Guava's `Multimap` is *very much* not designed to be used in the way you're using it, with a "Location without any values."  You'd probably be better off falling back to the traditional `Map<Key, Set<Value>>`.

Comment: Thanks. Obvious when you think about it. Well, maybe not :)

Comment: I got it working by doing the following, but it now adds duplicate keys? interconnects = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural(), Ordering.natural().nullsFirst());

I'm using multimap not Map because it provides so many nice methods that Map doesn't :)

Comment: What do you mean, "duplicate keys"?  At a first guess, I'd suspect your `Location.compareTo` implementation of being incorrect.